# How does Spring data binding work on the background?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, data-binding

I'm beginning to understand a little bit of what happens on the background when a user requests some URL in the context of a Spring MVC Web Application.
But I can't figure out when and how takes place the data binding, i.e. the mapping between the  fields of an input form to a model object and the later injection of that object in the related handler method.

Anybody knows which classes and methods are implied, and where does this appear in the documentation?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If, for example, you're posting data which represents `SomeBean` to this handler: `public void (SomeBean someBean)` the following happens in Spring 4.

- A `InvocableHandlerMethod` will iterate over the method's parameters and will ask a `HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite` instance to resolve the value for each parameter.
- The `HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite` will ask it's `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`s if they support the given parameter. If one supports the parameter this one is used for resolving the value.
- A `ModelAttributeMethodProcessor` will support the given parameter (`SomeBean`) and will try to resolve it's value.
- Inside it's `resolveArgument` method the `ModelAttributeMethodProcessor` will instantiate a target object of parameter's type.
- It then will call a `WebDataBinderFactory` to create a `WebDataBinder` which is responsible for binding the request to the target object.
- Once binded, the target will be returned and provided as an argument for the handler method.

P.s. Instead of the documentation you should read the source code.

Comment: Thank you very much, now I can start digging in those classes :) And +1 for "Instead of the documentation you should read the source code"